Build failed due to error 'Export encountered errors on following paths: '
I am facing an error when I try to build my project locally and on Vercel. The build fails with the following error:
**the error **
Export encountered errors on following paths: /(dashboard)/dashboard/edit-resume/page: /dashboard/edit-resume error Command failed with exit code 1. info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
If I comment out the useSearchParams part, the build completes successfully.
I have also tried using Suspense like below, but it didn’t resolve the issue:
My code
The error appears to be related to useSearchParams from next/navigation. Here's the problematic code snippet:
`import { useSearchParams } from "next/navigation";

const router = useRouter();
const searchParams = useSearchParams();
const search = searchParams.get("template");
console.log("queryParams", search);
`

`return (
    <Suspense fallback={<Loader size="lg" />}>
        <div className="flex flex-col md:flex-row">
            // other codes
        </div>
    </Suspense>
);
`

I have searched stack overflow and github issues cannot find any solution, can anyone help me?


At last, solved the issue, I was giving the suspense in the component level but it should be at the parent of the component in my it is the loading.tsx component as I am using App router in next.js 14.
Thanks all.

I am also have the same Issue,


import { useSearchParams } from "next/navigation";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

const SubmitWishPage = () => {
    const searchParams = useSearchParams();

    const [name, setName] = useState("Anonymous");
    const [wish, setWish] = useState("");

    useEffect(() => {
        const nameParam = searchParams.get("name");
        const wishParam = searchParams.get("wish");

        if (nameParam) setName(nameParam);
        if (wishParam) setWish(wishParam);
    }, []);




As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking Ask Question. To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can follow this question. Once you have enough reputation, you can also add a bounty to draw more attention to this question. - From Review
